# Extract and combine values from an SQL dump

Tags: awk, sed, grep, sql

I have several large SQL dumps with very long lines, including one containing a version & subversion of the database in a long `INSERT` statement, formatted like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (...'version','v1.23'...'subversion','45'...
```

I would like to parse the files and have an output combining the version & subversion into something like `v1.23-45`, by itself if one file is given, and on multiple lines preceded by filenames if more than one file is given, one line per file, i.e.,

```
file1: v1.23-45
file2: v6.78-91
```

I have the following attempt using sed, but (1) it assumes version always comes before subversion (not necessarily unreasonable, but inelegant), and (2) does not print filenames:

```bsh
sed -ns "s/.*'version','\([^']*\)'.*'subversion','\([^']*\)'.*/\1-\2/p" file ...
```

I also have the following attempt using grep, but it prints the result for each file on two lines (which I can combine by piping the output to `pr -ts -2`, bt only for a single file case):

```bsh
grep -oP "'(sub)?version','\K[^']*" file ...
```

I haven't tried with awk...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Would you not be able to query the actual database (not the dump of it) for this?

Comment: @Kusalananda: the dumps would have to be loaded into a live database first.  I create the database (import the dump) based on its version.